# CodeIgniter; disable login after nth unsuccessful attempts

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, login-attempts

I want to workout a functionality such that unsuccessful login attempts of users are capped at 5, then serve them a message to that effect.

Below is my codes:

```
$attempts = $this->input->post('attempts');

if ($attempts <= '5')
{
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->set('attempts', '`attempts`+ 1', FALSE);
    $this->db->update('tb_user');
}
else
{
    echo "Your account is locked!";
}
```

The above codes can update the database table and column attempts but records are still updating after the 5 attempts as in: storing the 6th, 7th, and nth unsuccessful login attempts.

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Block user after 3 login attempt using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974429/block-user-after-3-login-attempt-using-php)

Comment: What you do is simple. For every failed attempts, log it to your database. Show a warning message before the fifth attempt, then block on the fifth attempt. Use this with the timestamp

Comment: Your storing the attempts in a post variable for one... Presumably not even incrementing it. I mean a user could just change it to 1 and start all over with the brute Force.

Comment: so what should I do? I'm badly stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the attemps count from database instead of passing from frontend.

```
$attempts = $this->db->where('username', $username)->get('tb_user')->row()->attempts;

    if ($attempts > 4)
    {
        echo "Your account is locked!";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->set('attempts', ($attempts + 1), FALSE);
        $this->db->update('tb_user');
    }
```

Comment: It's not working. After 5 attempts records are still storing in database.

Comment: check your attempts field having type of `int`.

Comment: I tried your updated codes and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: nice to hear that. then you can accept my answer :D